# Glide is not a constructor, al tratar de usarlo con el bundler parcel

Tags: javascript, glide

Estoy usando [Glide](https://github.com/glidejs/glide) para hacer carruseles, tengo un problema estoy usando parcel para modularizar mi código javascript y css, instale la librería usando npm.

Luego importe la dependencia en mi código de esta forma:

```
import {Glide} from "@glidejs/glide/";
```

Y bien luego quise ( a como dice la guia de github) usar el constructor para inicializar el componente y obtengo el error `TypeError: _glide.Glide is not a constructor`

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como pone en la [documentación](https://glidejs.com/docs/setup#using-es-modules) tienes que  importar `Glide` y  no `{ Glide }`

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

new Glide('.glide').mount()
```